# copying specific cell value from multiple dgv to a specific cell in all rows of dgv by loop

Tags: vb.net

I have two forms: form2 with a dgv, form3 with a tabcontrol having a number of tab pages each of them with a dgv inserted. I want to get the cell(1) value of each row in form2 dgv equal to the value of cell(1) of row(13) in multiple dgv of form3 so that:

```
 DataGridView1.Rows(0).Cells(1).Value = Form3.DataGridView1.Rows(13).Cells(1).Value
    DataGridView1.Rows(1).Cells(1).Value = Form3.DataGridView2.Rows(13).Cells(1).Value
    DataGridView1.Rows(2).Cells(1).Value = Form3.DataGridView3.Rows(13).Cells(1).Value, etc.
```

I am trying the following code:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1        'dgv in form2

        For Each tp As TabPage In Form3.TabControl1.Controls.OfType(Of TabPage)()
            For Each dgv As DataGridView In tp.Controls.OfType(Of DataGridView)()
                 DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value = dgv.Rows(13).Cells(1).Value
            Next
        Next
    Next
```

But as a result, only the last dgv in form3 tabcontrol shows the requested data for all rows of form2 dgv. What am I missing, any help highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you are looping through the tabpages inside of the for so it will always land on the last tab for i=0, i=1 etc

```
    Dim i As Integer = 0 
    For Each tp As TabPage In Form3.TabControl1.Controls.OfType(Of TabPage)()
        For Each dgv As DataGridView In tp.Controls.OfType(Of DataGridView)()
            If i < DataGridView1.Rows.Count Then
                DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value = dgv.Rows(13).Cells(1).Value
                1 += 1
            End If
        Next
     Next
```

Comment: With i += 1 instead it works much better (!). Thanks.